# Error:java: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags when trying to run maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm new to maven but I would like to use it to run simple deeplearing4j program. After adding all the necessary dependencies I get the following: 
`Error:java: release version 5 not supported`
After following the instructions at [this](https://dev.to/techgirl1908/intellij-error-java-release-version-5-not-supported-376) page (changing my SDK, language and target byte code to 11)
[image] 
[image]

I'm getting this:

```
Error:java: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeTags
Error:java: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I've also tried setting JDK 14 but I get the same error. Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Deep</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.11</maven.compiler.target>
        <dl4j.version>0.9.1</dl4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-native-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
            <artifactId>datavec-api</artifactId>
            <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>nd4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-beta3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>deeplearning4j-play_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

If anybody can shed some light on what I might be doing wrong here I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is wrong.

```xml
<maven.compiler.source>1.11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.11</maven.compiler.target>
```

**Post Java 1.9, the version naming has changed. Make the following changes in the pom.xml.**

```xml
<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
```

The same convention follows from 10+ Java version.

The real issue is: one of library *org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-core:jar:0.9.1:compile* this jar having a dependency on *org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.16:compile*.

So this was an issue with Lombok which they fixed in a later version. To see all transitive dependencies you can do a `mvn dependency:tree` and see all transitive dependencies of the libraries you have brought in.

I have included the below dependency in the pom and that resolved the issue.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same errors. Is there anything else it could be?

Comment: Let me run the pom and check. Is the entire pom? Or do you have any other trimmed anything for brevity ?

Comment: Nope, that's all of it.

Comment: What is the maven version you are using for build ?

Comment: version 3.6.1 according to the settings

Comment: Edited the answer. The main issue is the deeplearning4j-core lib having a dependency on Lombok 1.16.x. including the1.18.2 in the pom and that fixed the issue. You can also try bumping up the version to more latest in case you want to and check.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the lombok dependency but that seems to have done it. Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks. Replacing lombok with 1.18.2 works.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue as I was using Lombok. And maven showed this warning:
`WARNING: Illegal reflective access by lombok.javac.apt.Processor (file:/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.14.8/lombok-1.14.8.jar) to field com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.processorClassLoader`

Comment: Ran into similar issue when running `mvn:build`. Changing lombok version to `1.18.22` helped

Comment: Adding Lombok does the trick.

Answer (score 22):

Add this to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.20</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've to build a maven project with JDK 11 but the -target and -source have to be Java 8. With the proposed solution I was able to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: How is this different to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63438394/2985643) which was posted a year before yours?

Answer (score 13):

It could be a reason of getting this issues while running application Intellij that you haven't configuration Project SDK setting in IDE.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I also got this error, when using jdk 10 to compile java8 source code.

[image: maven compile error]

After changing environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to jdk8 home dir, this error disappear.

Comment: This was also my issue. I had accidentally changed the jdk to a different version earlier then forgot about it when attempting `mvn install`. `mvn -version` will tell you the jdk maven is using, ensure it's the right one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jdk8 to run your project and still face the same error.
Please follow the following 2 steps.

1. check whether you're able to execute your maven project from IntelliJ's maven bar, instead of from the terminal.
2. If your project builds then check whether your JAVA_HOME is setup correctly. (In my case I switched from bash to zsh, and JAVA_HOME. was not setup)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this enough to put it above the other answers. IntelliJ (2021.2.1 Ultimate) ignored ignored the value set in the pom.xml, ignored the value in the Preferences, ignored JAVA_HOME, and used JDK 11 instead of 8!

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced that problem.
Check the JAVA_HOME variable. For ubuntu, go to the terminal and write `echo $JAVA_HOME`. If you see the difference between this and `java -version` you will need to set the appropriate version of JDK to your JAVA_HOME like below
`export JAVA_HOME=YOUR_JDK_BIN_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I was able to solve by changing JDK version from 11 to 8. By the way, this is not running in 8 mode using JDK 11. You actually need a JDK 8 bundle.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).